# PHP Get value of a level in multidimensional array using function arguments as "path"

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with N levels like this:

```
$a = array(
'a'=>1,
'b'=>array(
    'x'=>array(
        'p'=>array(
            't'=>2
        )
    )
),
'c'=>3
);
```

How can I get the value by "path" using an array of arguments in a function?

```
function get(){
   $args = func_get_args();
   $b = (global) $a;
   // ????
}
$v = get('b','x','p'); // expected: Array ( [t] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get() {
    global $a;
    $current = $a;
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $key) {
        $current = $current[$key];
    }
    return $current;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit more php-way of doing this:

```
function array_get_path(array $array, $path) {
  $current = $array;

  if(!empty($path)) {
    foreach($path as $elem) {
      if(isset($current[$elem])) {
        $current = &$current[$elem];
      } else {
        return $current;
      }
    }
  }

  return $current;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "bit more php-way" ?

Comment: Naming and using array as argument, like in stdlib

Answer (score 0):

Walk down your arguments array one element at a time:

```
function get() {   
    global $a;
    $args = func_get_args();
    $currentElement = $a;

    foreach ($args as $index) {
        $currentElement = $currentElement[$index];
    }

    return $currentElement;
}
```